Mailcoach laravel send Campaign issue using mailcoach docs
I'm experiencing an issue with Mailcoach where my campaign gets stuck on loading and does not send. I have set it up using an existing app following the methods described in the Mailcoach documentation. Despite trying various troubleshooting steps, I can't seem to resolve the problem.
Here’s what I have done so far:
Checked Server Logs: Looked through the server logs but couldn't pinpoint any specific errors or warnings related to this issue.
Verified Configuration: Double-checked all configuration settings, including mail server, database, and queue settings. Everything seems to be in order.
Queue Configuration: Ensured that the queue is properly configured and running. I have a queue worker running, but the campaign still does not proceed past the loading stage.
Any insights or additional steps I should consider to resolve this issue?
mailocah dashboard view. http://127.0.0.1:8001/mailcoach/campaigns 

I'm not familiar with Mailcoach. When you say the campaign is not getting past the loading stage, is that something in your Laravel code, or within the Mailcoach GUI? What is loading, where is it loading, what is the code that does the loading, is there anything in the Developer Console of your browser?

hey I have setup mailcoach campaigns according to documentations when i launch a campaign it gets stuck and keeps on loading

@aynber i added mailcoah dashboard pic

I'm having the same issue, jobs to send campaign mails are not dispatched. @Shery have managed to solve this?

If you have the self-hosted mailcoach on your local, then it's possible that your cron is not triggering scheduled commands. In that case you need to manually run the artisan command (example php artisan mailcoach:send-campaign-mails). This should queue jobs for sending mails.
